# Iterate a string with Regex and JS

Tags: javascript, regex, key-value

I have a set of structured data into a string and I need to iterate over it through regular espression in Javascript.

This is an example of the data:

```
|KEY1|VALUE 1 |KEY2| VALUE 2 |KEY3| OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, |PIPES| AND WHAT YOU WANT |KEY4| VALUE4
```

I need to parse them and create a structured object (or an array) like this:

```
myObject.KEY1 = "VALUE 1"
myObject.KEY2 = "VALUE 2"
myObject.KEY3 = "OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, AND WHAT YOU WANT"
myObject.KEY4 = "VALUE4"
```

I've got the keys with that simple regex:`[|](.+?)[|]` but I don't know how to iterate through them and thei respective values.

Comment: If you are allowed to have your delimiter `|` in your data then you _must_ have some way to escape it.  There is absolutely no way to distinguish that `|PIPES|` is not a new key, followed by a new value.  Even if keys have a very rigid format, I can always put something that _looks_ like a key in the data. e.g. `|KEY3| OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, \|PIPES\| AND WHAT YOU WANT`

Comment: You are right. I've looked through the data and there isn't that occourrence. So forgot the meta-pipe problem ;)

Comment: @Pennywise83 What kind of source is delivering data in this format?

Comment: Why regex? This seems like a simple string manipulation problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that a key is defined by the expression `\|KEY[0-9]+\|`, since that's the simplest way to include `|KEY1|` through `|KEY4|` while also excluding `|PIPES|`.

If your goal is to use a loop and regex matches, as opposed to a single convoluted regex or doing actual parsing with functions like indexOf(), then **this can be done with negative lookahead**.

```
var x = "|KEY1|VALUE 1 |KEY2| VALUE 2 |KEY3| OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, |PIPES| AND WHAT YOU WANT |KEY4| VALUE4";

var map = {};

while(x.length > 0) {
    var key = x.match(/\|KEY[0-9]+\|/)[0];
    x = x.substr(key.length);
    var value = x.match(/(.(?!\|KEY[0-9]+\|))*/)[0];
    x = x.substr(value.length);
    map[key] = value;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(map, null, 4));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eyL7yhwr/

Answer (score 2):

This will do it.

```js
//using regex
var keyString = "|KEY1|VALUE 1 |KEY2| VALUE 2 |KEY3| OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, |PIPES| AND WHAT YOU WANT |KEY4| VALUE4"
var cases = keyString.match(/[^|]+/g)
var myObject = {};
if (cases.length > 0)
  {
     for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i += 2)
     {
       myObject[cases[i].toString()] = cases[i+1].trim();
     }
  }
  
  document.write(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Comment: The sample output in the question shows that "|PIPES|" is not supposed to be one of the keys, so this answer is incorrect (unless he changes his mind about that requirement).

Comment: @Ixrec "*You are right. I've looked through the data and there isn't that occourrence. So forgot the meta-pipe problem ;)*" as commented by the OP.

Comment: In retrospect it's hard to tell whether he actually wanted "|PIPES|" to be a key or not, so I'll just +1 and we'll call it a draw.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var s = "|KEY1|VALUE 1 |KEY2| VALUE 2 |KEY3| OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, |PIPES| AND WHAT YOU WANT |KEY4| VALUE4";

s.match(/\|(KEY\d+)\|.*?(?=\|KEY\d|$)/g).reduce(function (res, v) { 
  var match = v.match(/(KEY\d+)\|(.*?)\s*$/);
  res[match[1]] = match[2];
  return res;
}, {})
```

another solution even easier:

```js
var s = "|KEY1|VALUE 1 |KEY2| VALUE 2 |KEY3| OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, |PIPES| AND WHAT YOU WANT |KEY4| VALUE4";

var v, res = {}, match = s.match(/\s*\|KEY\d+\|\s*|.+?(?=\s*\|KEY\d|$)/g);
while(v = match.shift()) 
  res[v.replace(/^[\s|]*|[\s|]*$/g, '')] = match.shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `exec` and `/[^|]+/g` will get you a nice array.

```
var str = "|KEY1|VALUE 1 |KEY2| VALUE 2 |KEY3| OTHER VALUE WITH ANY CHARACTER LIKE SPACES, |PIPES| AND WHAT YOU WANT |KEY4| VALUE4";

var re = /[^|]+/g;

var arr = [];

while ((arr = re.exec(str)) !== null){
  console.log(arr[0].trim());
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/wugacumaku/2/edit)

It's a bit simpler than some other regex here, and I think it's a bit more readable. I also used `trim()`, which you'll have to use [the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Polyfill) if you want to support before IE9.